# Getting vimux to work on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: vim, terminal, tmux

The error message when running

`:h vimux` is

`E149: Sorry, no help for vimux.`

It seem that vimux is not working at all.

Am I missing something really basic?

- I installed vimux by cloning the https://github.com/benmills/vimux.git repository from github to ~/.vim/bundle where a vimux directory was established.
- I run Ubuntu 13.10 and try to use vimux from gvim. (In any case, the same error persists when using vim from the terminal)

I have been googling this for some hours now and am really stuck.

Comment: Which plugin manager (Pathogen / Vundle etc.) do you use? Are you sure it's working correctly (for other plugins)?

Comment: Pathogen, other stuff, for example NERDTree works fine.

Comment: You may have to run the `:helptags` command once to get the help. What's the output of `:scriptnames`, do the plugin's scripts appear?

Comment: That's interesting. '':scriptnames'' does not return anything related with Vimux. Seems the installation was not successful. Any hints on how to do it correctly (as noted above, I was cloning from the github repo)?

Comment: Downloading the zip file, extracting and placing the contents in ~/.vim/bundle/vimux-master/ doesn't help. I still cannot get the help on vimux, nor run a command in vimux.

Comment: Did you restart vim after cloning the repo?  Pathogen does its stuff when your vimrc tells it to, and plugins are loaded shortly after, so that would explain why `:scriptnames` does not show anything.  Pathogen provides the `:Helptags` command as a wrapper for `:helptags`, so you do not have to worry about the directory argument.  After `:Helptags`, you should be able to use `:help vmux`.

Comment: The '':Helptags'' solved part of the issue: '':he vimux'' is working in gvim; However, vimux commands still cannot be run.

Comment: Found the reason for this not working (doooh):

Comment: Found the reason for this not working (doooh): "So you run a tmux session first, then vim, then ':call VimuxRunCommand("foo")'" --> taken from Harry Moreno at https://www.braintreepayments.com/braintrust/vimux-simple-vim-and-tmux-integration

Comment: Please post that an an answer, or delete your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vimux **cannot** be run from an ordinary (g)vim session. Instead, vim must be started from **within** tmux. 
Then, vimux works flawlessly.
Thanks @Ingo_Karkat for guiding me towards the solution.